# Consider the system of equations $x+y=2$, $ax+y=b$.Find the conditions on $a$ and $b$ under which the following holds

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Consider the system of equations $x+y=2$, $ax+y=b$.Find the conditions on $a$ and $b$ under which
  (i) the system has exactly one solution;
 (ii) the system has no solution;
(iii) the system has more than one solution.

I solved for $x$ and $y$ in terms of $a$ and $b$ and got some restricting conditions. But, it is difficult to solve that way. I was wondering if it could be solved like the determinants or matrices with Cramer's Rule or something similar because I read similar about similar conditions there. Please help!

Comment: Use http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CramersRule.html

Comment: I need to use $x,y,1$ to solve, right?

Comment: @Hwak, two unknowns and two variables

Comment: Now I do not get it.

Comment: Please find the condition part in the link

Comment: I have read it, but I find it a little complicated to apply in this case.

Comment: I could do the 'no solution' part. Please help with the others. I do not get a clue

Comment: @Hawk: Are you familiar with Gaussian Elimination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking carefully at this system we can answer the questions by inspection , hardly doing any arithmetic at all.

$ \ \ x + y = 2 \\ 
ax + y = b $

The coefficients of y are equal therefore there are two cases.

Case 1

If a = 1 then the left hand sides of the equations are identical. If $b \ne 2 $ then the lines are parallel (not coinciding) , therefore no solution. If b = 2 then the lines (are parallel) coincide , therefore infinite number of solutions.

Case 2

If $ a \ne 1 $ then there is no way to make the left hand sides identical (parallel) because of the y coefficients therefore there will be a unique solution.

Summary

(i) Unique solution for $a \ne 1 $

(ii) No solution for $ a = 1 $ AND $ b \ne 2 $

(iii) Infinite number of solutions for $ a = 1 $ AND $ b = 2 $

Answer (score 0):

for case  1  you have following matrix

```
 1, 1
 a, 1
```

unique solution would have if determinant of this matrix is not zero,in this case $1-a$ is not  zero,or $a$ is not equal to $1$,

now

$x+y=2$

$a*x+y=b$

if rank of coeficient matrix is not equal to rank of  augmented  matrix rank,then it has not solution,

and finally if this rank is equal,but less then number ofvariables,then it has many solution,like determiant of

```
1   1
 a   1
```

is zero or $a=1$

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations

Comment: I could not understand. Please elaborate your solution.

Comment: it is  basic linear algebra  topics,$A*x=b$ system has unique solution if only if  determinant  of $A$ is not  zero, for   not have solution is that rank of $A$ and rank $[A , B]$ must be different,for having infinity solution these ranks must be equal and less then number of variables

Comment: did you get point?

Comment: if $D_x=0,D=0$ and $D_y=0,D=0$ then infinite solution or if any one holds then infinite solution?

Answer (score 0):

to find inconsistency that means no solution of equations we must have
rank of coefficient matrix A = rank of augmented matrix [A,C]
now here augmented matrix

```
1  1  2      1    1      2
         =   
a  1  b      0  (a-1)  (2a-b)
```

now if a≠1 & 2a=b then rank(A)≠rank(C)
system has no solution
 if a=1 & 2a=b then rank(A)=rank(C)=1 < no.of variables n i.e 2
system has infinitely many solution
 if a≠1 & 2a≠b then rank(A)=rank of(C)=2=n
system has unique solution
 I hope u get the answer & process.GOOD QUESTION